# Remove Bootstrap Navbar Collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that looks like this: (See EDIT)

The only HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="games.html">Games</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="cafe.html">Cafe</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- END navbar list -->
```

I want the it not to collapse vertically and stay in a vertical bar on all screen sizes.

Does anybody have any css snippet that can remove the responsiveness?

EDIT2: http://jsfiddle.net/9KMR6/5/ I tried copy pasting some of the styles from bootstrap's non repsonsive example but I have an issue where other elements such as the image in the fiddle overlaps the navbar so the links stop working... Does anbody know why/how to fix?

Comment: I really don't understand what do you need... go to http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar and try again

Comment: I did it's a problem with media queries I just don't know which one it is!

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system), try setting `@grid-float-breakpoint` to a very low value such as `1px`.

Comment: I have made a lot of edits to my bootstrap css files so I can't edit the variables now...

Comment: In that case you'll need to search for all CSS rules that are associated with the event of the collapsing navbar and override them. I think there will be quite a few and am unsure of them off the top of my head.

Comment: I tried copy pasting some of the styles from bootstrap's non repsonsive example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9KMR6/5/) but I have an issue where other elements such as the image in the fiddle overlaps the navbar so the links stop working... Does anbody know why/how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's a media query inside the CSS file that automatically collapses the menu beneath a certain screen width.

<strike>If you can find the CSS files that apply to your page, try posting them here.</strike>

Alright, default bootstrap, eh? [Their documentation defines small screens as their default state](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries); all the other media queries scale up.

[They also have a section on disabling the responsive behavior.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)  Unfortunately...

> As a heads up, the navbar component is rather tricky here in that the styles for displaying it are rather specific and detailed. Overrides to ensure desktop styles display are not as performant or sleek as one would like. Just be aware there may be potential gotchas as you build on top of this example when using the navbar. -[getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/)

I'm officially out of my depth here, sorry. Maybe you can figure something out from their documentation.

Comment: Yeah it's just default bootstrap that's all the CSS I'm using, the question is what media query is it?

Comment: hmmm is there any way you could you recreate the navbar-nav without the media queries?

Comment: Possibly, but you'd have to take the CSS found in one of the "large screen" queries, and replace the default CSS styling for it with it. Without an intimate familiarity with how bootstrap handles the show/hide, I can't recommend a specific method.